# jquery slide's for step method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-slide-effects

Am using jquery slide(down/up) effect for a step process there i struck.i don't know how to slide up the id if it was not selected are used see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VivekNadar/4BYaE/2/)  it clear my doubt

```
$(function(){
        $('ul.new_checkout li > .title').on('click', function(){
            var id=$(this).attr('id');
            var rep=id.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-');
            console.log("id:" +rep);
            if(rep){
               $("#"+rep).slideDown('fast');
              }
                 })
           });

 <ul class="new_checkout">
    <li>
         <div class="title" id="step-1"> Step-1</div>
     <div class="content" id="step1"></div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

how sholud i slide up a step id if i click other steps? help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer finally [fiddle to my answer](http://jsfiddle.net/VivekNadar/4BYaE/3/)

hiding the content before the step show.

```
$('ul.new_checkout li > .title').on('click', function(){
  var id=$(this).attr('id');
  var rep=id.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-');
  console.log("id:" +rep);
  if(rep){
    $('.content').slideUp('slow');
    $("#"+rep).slideDown('fast');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('ul.new_checkout li > .title').on('click', function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    var rep=id.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-');
    console.log("id:" +rep);
    if(rep){
      $(".content").slideUp('fast');
      $("#"+rep).slideDown('fast');
    }
  })
});

<ul class="new_checkout">
  <li>
     <div class="title" id="step-1"> Step-1</div>
     <div class="content" id="step1"></div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

This will slide the other divs up when it slide the corrrect one down.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4BYaE/4/) is the updated fiddle.